# meta theme-color not with dark mode in Android Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am trying to give custom color to the chrome search bar using `<meta name="theme_color" content="#0000f2">`.

Its working fine if the system default is set to Light Theme but it is not working if the system default is set to Dark Mode.

I would like to know how can I solve this problem.

Thanks for any kind of help in advance.

PS: You can visit https://www.trippyadive.web.app to watch it live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible. The status of this feature issue is open, you can check out the details here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=980790

Comment: The comments say it's working as intended to UX specs.
It's not a bug, it's a feature ;)

Answer (score 0):

Before we can use `media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"` on `<meta>` tags, you can ​use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia).

```js
document
 ​.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]")
 ​.setAttribute("content", window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches ? "darkblue" : "lightblue");
```

You may also want to change the theme color along with OS setting changes.

```js
const updateTheme = () =>  {
 ​document
   ​.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]")
   ​.setAttribute("content", window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches ? "darkblue" : "lightblue");
}
updateTheme();
if (mediaQueryDark.addEventListener) {
 ​mediaQueryDark.addEventListener("change", updateTheme);
}
```

Safari < 14 does not support addEventListener on [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList)